# smart way to do calculation near int overflow

Tags: c, integer-overflow

Is there any smart way to fix this issue?

```
uint32_t a = 16637510;
uint32_t b = 45627362;
uint32_t c = 0;
c = a * 100000 / b //overflows
c = (a * 100/b)*1000 //gives 36000
```

I need to get result c = 36463 or better 36464. And fast, non float operations are required. CPU is stm32f4

Update:

Accepted answer is converting 100000 to 100000ULL (64 bit) but as @PeterJ suggested (and deleted his answer) using stm32f4 FPU is faster then 64 dividing operations

```
Timer t;
int i;
t.start();
for(i = 1; i <= 100000; ++i) c = a * 100000ULL / b;
t.stop();
printf("64\ttakes %f seconds, du is %d\n", t.read(), c);
t.reset();
t.start();
for(i = 1; i <= 100000; ++i) c = (uint32_t)((float)a * 100000.0f / (float)b);
t.stop();
printf("float\ttakes %f seconds, du is %d\n", t.read(), c);
t.reset();
```

> 64 takes 0.086669 seconds, du is 57333
>   float  takes 0.017779 seconds, du is 57333

Comment: No worries. You do not like it - I delete it :)

Comment: Approximate 32-bit math only solutions exists.  What is the range of `a,b`?  What is the tolerable error (+/-1?)

Comment: How common are the overflows?  Are they an exception or  do they happen with every dataset?

Comment: @chux a, b will stay in range +/- 1000 error (+/-1) is ok.

Comment: @ensc on every dataset.

Comment: @PeterJ using FPU was 5x faster than 64bit dividing. You ware right.

Comment: But the solution is so bad as everyone says. So better follow others. I will stick to my experience.

Comment: @PeterJ don't be a child ! Just prove you right like I did.

Comment: Note that with a range of +/-1000 with `a,b` and a fixed 100000, `c` is always in the range 36460 to 36467, a range of 8. Hmmm , I see a number of narrow calculations that solve this.  In fact, I think you can get a good enough answer assuming `b` is always 45627362

Comment: Form compile time constants `uint32 B = 45627362/32, A = (16637510/B)*B` then `(a-A)*(100000/32)/(B/32) + (A/(B/32))` --> a nice answer.  just a 32-bit subtract, multiple, divide by constant and add.  `b` is irrelevant.

Comment: What compiler flags are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
c = a * 100000ULL / b; // gives 36463
```

See https://godbolt.org/g/aemCyw for the assembly that gcc generates for this operation and the original `c = a * 100000 / b` that overflows. Notice that `__aeabi_uldivmod` is used instead of `__aeabi_uidiv`.

Comment: In original code a is taken from Input Capture TIM so it should stay 32. I will do some speed tests to compare 64bit divisions with your float version

Answer (score 0):

When 64-bit math is expensive, sometimes a 32-bit only approximate solution can be significantly faster.  Depends on the processor/compiler.

Let us see what can be done using only 32-bit math.

---

`b == 100000 == 0x186A0` and let us assume it is fixed - a 17 bit number.

`a == 16637510 == 0x00FDDE46`, yet OP says it is within +/- 1000.  So it is a 24-bit number.   `b` is a 26-bit number.  With these restrictions, the final quotient will always be in the 36464 neighborhood (a 16-bit number)

We can scale the product operands `a,b` to use 16 or so significant bits of `a` and 16 or so most significant bits of `b` without losing much significance.  Then we have a 16-bit * 16-bit product which will not overflow 32-bit math.

We can take advantage that `b` has only 12 significant bits leaving code to use up to 20 (32-12) most significant bits of the 24-bit `a` in the product.

The intermediate product is 41-bit, so we need to scale the multiplication down at least 9 bits.

```
#define SCALE_A 4
#define SCALE_M 5
// Insure SCALE_A + SCALE_M >= 9 to avoid overflow
// Perhaps other scales like SCALE_A 8, SCALE_M 1 will be faster.

uint32_t scale(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
  uint32_t product = (a >> SCALE_A)*(100000 >> SCALE_M);
  uint32_t c = product/(b >> (SCALE_A + SCALE_M));
  return c;
}
```

If this faster/better for OP? Maybe.  Simply another approach to consider.  I'll leave it for users to in-line it for performance profiling.

Comment: Using `(uint16_t)(a >> 8)*(100000 >> 1)` might allow use of a 16*16 to 32 bit multiply as emitted code.